# join 3 lamp wires into one plug

Tags: electrical

I have 3 of these: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-Make-A-Lamp-Kit-7002500/100192701.

Instead of plugging all 3 of these into the wall, or into a splitter and then plugging it into the wall, I wanted to join all three of them into one wire that I plug into the wall.

I know this can be achieved by joining 3 wires for each connection on the socket and then splicing it into one cable that goes to the wall. However, I also realize that not knowing what you're doing with electricity can start house fires.

Each lamp socket will have a 100 watt bulb. So I assume the wire from that goes into the wall needs to have the right amps for it to work. But this is where I am lost.

And/or, instead of joining the 3+3 wires, is there some kind of junction box that does what I need?

Any ideas?

Comment: 300watts / 120volts = 2.5 amps. All wire connections need to be made in a listed box. Are all 3 fixtures going to be part of 1 assembly or are there going to be 3 separate fixtures?

Comment: Not sure what code says about external (ie, not a permanent part of the building) wiring. People splice wires all the time (ie, cord gets damaged in the middle) though the preferred method is to replace the entire cord so you're not left with wire nuts or a bunch of electrical tape around the splice. I'd use a junction box in your case, but I'm not sure if the standard 1/2" cable clamps would tighten down enough to be used with "lamp cord".

Comment: @EdBeal One fixture but I think I found an answer somewhere else that seems to work for me.